# No puedo asignar un formulario y que mantenga los valores en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, clase-abstracta

Estoy teniendo un problema ya que no puedo lograr asignar un objeto formulario para que se muestre con los valores que deseo.

Tengo el siguiente método

```
private void openForm<T>(List<Form> forms, Form frm) where T: Form 
    {
        T frmX;
        Form form = getForm(forms, frm);    //Se busca el formulario en la lista
        if (form != null)                   //Si existe se, se asigna el existente y se elimina 
        {
            frmX = (T)form;
            frm.Close();
            frm = null;
            frmX.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            frmX.Show();
            frmX.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {                   //Si no existe se abre con el nuevo objeto.
            
            
            frmX = (T)frm;
            frmX.MdiParent = this;

            //*****INICIO INICIALIZACION*****///
            frmX.MinimumSize = frmX.Size;
            Forma forma = new Forma(conexion);
             T frmY = (T)Multiple.CargarForma(frmX, this.Usuario.Id, forma); //Carga la forma según el usuario
           
            forms.Add(frmX);
            frmY.Show();
            frmY.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            frmY.BringToFront();

        }


    }
```

Básicamente lo que hace es fijarse si existe el formulario abierto (Si está en la lista). Si está, muestra ese, sinó abre uno nuevo.

Con la primer parte del código no tengo problema. Si el formulario ya está abierto lo trae tal cual.

El problema lo tengo con la segunda parte del código.

```
 frmX = (T)frm;
        frmX.MdiParent = this;

        //*****INICIO INICIALIZACION*****///
        frmX.MinimumSize = frmX.Size;
        Forma forma = new Forma(conexion);
         T frmY = (T)Multiple.CargarForma(frmX, this.Usuario.Id, forma); //Carga la forma según el usuario

        forms.Add(frmX);
        frmY.Show();
        frmY.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        frmY.BringToFront();
```

Si el formulario no está abierto tengo un método que trae como estaba abierto la última vez (Size, Location, state, y algunos atributos propios).

El tema es que cuando hace la asignación

```
T frmY = (T)Multiple.CargarForma(frmX, this.Usuario.Id, forma); //Carga la forma según el usuario
```

frmY.Location es igual (x:0, Y:0) en vez de la ubicación que tiene de verdad. Y con size me pasa lo mismo.

El método devuelve un objeto tipo Form que yo lo casteo en T, que es el formulario que se está abriendo.

Probé asignar a un tipo Form y pasa lo mismo. Probé asingar Multiple.CargarForma(frmX, this.Usuario.Id, forma).location.X y tiene el valor que debe tener.

Se me ocurrió el que Form tal vez no se pueda asignar directamente pero tampoco encontré una  forma de clonarlo.

¿Alguna idea que pueda utilizar?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente alternativa, y es usar el **patrón Singleton** para construir los formularios:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Form1 frm = null;

    public static Form1 GetForm()
    {
        if (frm == null)
        {
            frm = new Form1();                
        }

        frm.Propiedad1 = Valor1;
        frm.Propiedad2 = Valor2;
        frm.PropiedadX = ValorX;

        return frm;
    }
}
```

Para poder usar el **patrón Singleton** en la construcción de un formulario debes poner al constructor del formulario como privado y declarar una variable privada que sea del mismo tipo que tu formulario, en este caso la variable se llama **frm**.

Como tu constructor es privado ya no puedes construir al formulario como lo haces normalmente, es decir ya no puedes hacer:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
```

Por tanto debes hacer un **método estático** que se encargue de la construcción del formulario. Dentro de este método preguntamos si la **variable frm** es nula, de serlo quiere decir que este formulario nunca ha sido construido, por tanto lo construimos, posteriormente configuramos las propiedades que queramos del formulario con los valores deseados y por último retornamos el formulario. Si la **variable frm** no es nula quiere decir que ya este formulario fue construido por tanto no lo construimos de nuevo, pero configuramos las propiedades que queramos del formulario con los valores deseados y retornamos la **variable frm**.

El **patrón Singleton** nos garantiza que un objeto sea construido solo una vez.

Para hacer uso del código anterior podrías hacer:

```
var miForm = Form1.GetForm();

miForm.ShowDialog();
```

Guardamos en la **variable miForm** el formulario que se retorna al llamar al **método GetForm** y posteriormente lo mostramos en pantalla.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Voy a probarlo para ver que tal me funciona y te cuento.

Comment: @MRossi podrías decirme si la respuesta dada te resulto útil, gracias

Comment: Si. Funciona bien. Igualmente utilicé la idea para un desarrollo nuevo. El que ya había hecho no lo quería modificar. Lo que hice en desarrollo que ya tenía fue no encapsular el funcionamiento y escribir directamente sobre las propiedades de formulario que iba a modificar. Muchas Gracias por la idea por que me sirve para sacarme un dolor de cabeza

Comment: @MRossi que bueno que te haya servido, podrias por favor marcar la respuesta como aceptada, gracias

Comment: Listo. Me habia re olvidado.